# I am getting the error, Can not find the module './--require.js' using mocha

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, mocha.js, babeljs

I am trying to write the unit test case using mocha and chai but I am getting the error:-`Cannot find module './--require.js` when I run the test case.

the script is:- `"test": "mocha --require babel-core/register 'server/api/**/*.test.js'"`

full error:-

````
D:\gitlab-to-azure\blik-app\node_modules\yargs\yargs.js:1163
      else throw err
           ^

Error: Cannot find module './--require.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.getConstants (D:/gitlab-to-azure/blik-app/server/config/environment/index.js:12:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:/gitlab-to-azure/blik-app/server/app.js:20:25)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at loader (D:\gitlab-to-azure\blik-app\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (D:\gitlab-to-azure\blik-app\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:/gitlab-to-azure/blik-app/server/api/group/group.test.js:2:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at loader (D:\gitlab-to-azure\blik-app\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (D:\gitlab-to-azure\blik-app\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at D:\gitlab-to-azure\blik-app\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:334:36
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (D:\gitlab-to-azure\blik-app\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:331:14)
    at Mocha.run (D:\gitlab-to-azure\blik-app\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:809:10)
    at Object.exports.singleRun (D:\gitlab-to-azure\blik-app\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\run-helpers.js:108:16)
    at exports.runMocha (D:\gitlab-to-azure\blik-app\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\run-helpers.js:142:13)
    at Object.exports.handler.argv [as handler] (D:\gitlab-to-azure\blik-app\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\run.js:292:3)
    at Object.runCommand (D:\gitlab-to-azure\blik-app\node_modules\yargs\lib\command.js:242:26)
    at Object.parseArgs [as _parseArgs] (D:\gitlab-to-azure\blik-app\node_modules\yargs\yargs.js:1087:28)
    at Object.parse (D:\gitlab-to-azure\blik-app\node_modules\yargs\yargs.js:566:25)
    at Object.exports.main (D:\gitlab-to-azure\blik-app\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\cli.js:68:6)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\gitlab-to-azure\blik-app\node_modules\mocha\bin\mocha:164:29)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)```


Folder Structure:-
server
  api
   groups
     controller.js
     model.js
     groups.test.js
````

Answer (score -1):

You would need to qualify for the full path for the mocha runner, you can try something like this

```
"test": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha --compilers js:@babel/register 'server/api/**/*.test.js'"
```

Comment: Jawed it's not working and by the way ```--compilers``` are deprecated.